# spsc_queue pop - avoid memcpy?

Tags: c++, boost, low-latency

I declare `spsc_queue` like this:

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<fut_sess_contents,  boost::lockfree::capacity<1024>> futInfoUpdates;
```

I process it this way:

```
fut_sess_contents entry_fsc;
while (futInfoUpdates.pop(entry_fsc))
{
    .... work
}
```

I assume I pass `entry_fsc` here by reference and `spsc_queue` `memcpy` next element. It does not look effective, I would prefer just get pointer to the item in storage and work with item from storage directly(avoiding extra `memcpy`). Can I do this somehow? My storage is big enough and I process it fast enough so I'm sure that I can work with pointer from storage directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

This is exactly required so the SPSC queue can be implemented in a lockfree fashion (assuming fixed capacity).

You can't have your cake and eat it, too

Also, you're way past micro-optimizing.

> **Did your profiler tell you this is your performance bottleneck?** (*Hint*: No, it didn't).

Comment: Why using extra memcpy when you can avoid it? You don't need profiler to know that memcpy is slower than "no memcpy". I think `spsc_queue` is too general. Just give me pointer to item in storage I can guarantee safety myself.

Comment: If you want to "guarantee safety yourself" don't ask for a safe container! Use std::vector, or std::list. And you'll find that the first is unwieldy/impossible to get right for lock-free access and std::list is going to be slow (even if you use a custom allocator and re-implement it to use atomic exchanges for all pointer updates). In other words: you are underestimating things here. Of course _you can just store raw pointers inside your spsc queue_

Answer (score 0):

Once an item has been popped from the queue, its content may be *overwritten* at any point in time; and sooner rather than later if the queue is full or close to full.

Therefore, it is *essential* that the content be moved/copied out before the item is marked as popped, otherwise you would get memory corruption.

If you want just a pointer to the element... the solution is to make a queue of pointers. Define your queue over a `boost::shared_ptr<fut_sess_contents>` and just that pointer will be copied (in C++11, if supported, you should prefer a `std::unique_ptr<fut_sess_contents>`).

Comment: IIRC these types aren't supported in SPSC (or maybe only iff using fixed capacity). Which is why I suggested the raw pointers. We can manage the lifetime externally (yes, this will induce locking on garbage collect, which is the bane of concurrent containers without the patented reclamation schemes that aren't part of Boost)

Comment: @sehe: I find that surprising, could you expand why the normal copy/move methods cannot be used within SPSC ?

Comment: The way I remember, SPSC requires the element type to be trivial. Move methods don't add value there.

Comment: There is no requirement for boost's SPSC queue, you can create a queue of shared pointers if you want.  Unfortunately they do not support move semantic on removing items from the queue, which means you cannot create a useful queue of std::unique_ptr.